# How can I write a query that returns two different columns for two different conditions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

I have a Microsoft SQL Server table that has three columns in it - one for *Locations*, one for the associated *Images* and one indicating whether a given image is meant be used as the **main** Image for a **given location** (this is done because historically multiple images were uploaded for each location and this column indiciated which image is the **one** that actually gets used).

Now we want to be able pick and assign a **second image** as a logo for our locations, resulting in a fourth column added to indiciate which image becomes that logo.

So I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+----------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
| filename | location |    IsMainImage  |    IsLogo |
+----------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
|  img1    |       10 |         True    |      Null |
|  img2    |       10 |         Null    |      True |
|  img3    |       10 |         Null    |      Null |
|  img4    |       20 |         True    |      Null |
|  img5    |       20 |         NULL    |      True |
+----------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
```

My goal is to write a query that would return both img1 and img2 as different columns within the same row in my query, followed by img3 and img4 another row. From the table above I need the output to look like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| filename1 | filename2   | 
+-----------+-------------+
|  img1     |      img2   |
|  img4     |      img5   |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Please note that my description is an oversimplication. I am modifying and SSIS package that is consumed by another proces that I cannot modify. This is the reason why I need the output in this format.
What became Filename1 and Filename2 used to be the same file (logo was a resized version of the main image) and now I need to differentiate between the two.

It is crucial that only the columns flagged as IsMainImage show under filename1 and only the columns flagged under IsLogo show under filename2.

I would appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Case expression:

```
SELECT max(CASE WHEN [IsMainImage] = 'True' then filename end) as filename1,
        max(CASE WHEN [IsLogo] = 'True' then filename end) as filename2
        from Table_testcase group  by location;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will try it out shortly and will let you know.

Comment: Aside: It's a `case` [_expression_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), not [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/statements?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Dont understand. Could you please edit your answer and paste the query which is causing issue ?

Comment: This works as far as answering my question goes and I marked as the answer. Thank you! The unexpected issue I am running into is being able to use this as a subquery since it result in "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS".

Comment: Mohd Atif, first of all, my sincere thank you. You really did answer my question. What I am dealing with is the result of it being a portion of a bigger query. I will attempt to include it as part of my question - perhaps as a comment once I figure out how to present it.

Comment: @user1179071 - Question asked and answered. If you have a new question then please post it as such.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table with itself, something like this:

```
SELECT im1.filename as filename1,im2.filename as filename2
FROM images im1
JOIN images im2
     ON im1.location = im2.location
     AND im2.IsLogo = 1
WHERE im1.IsMainImage  = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This is close, however it only returns rows for locations that have both images set. All other locations are ignored, which may become an issue. I realize this is not immediately clear from my description.